# Jasmine test for AngularJS $locationChangeSuccess

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

How would I write a test for this following piece of code?

```
        $scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function () {
            $(".modal-backdrop").removeClass('modal-backdrop');
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
beforeEach(function() {
  $('body').append('<div id="test" class="modal-backdrop"/>');
});

afterEach(function() {
  $('#test').remove();
});

it('should remove the classname on $locationChangeSuccess', function() {
  spyOn($scope, '$on').and.callThrough();

  $scope.$broadcast('$locationChangeSuccess');

  expect($scope.$on).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect($('#test').hasClass('modal-backdrop')).toBe(false);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To trigger the handler function you need to trigger the event in the test. That can be done like this:

```
$scope.$broadcast('$locationChangeSuccess');
```

Comment: thanks, I appreciate the tip. I guess I'm also asking how would I write a legitimate test for this?