# karma test rootScope.$on $locationChangeSuccess

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-jasmine

I have a small piece of code that simply reloads the current window on `$locationChangeSuccess`:

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function(){
    self.window.location.reload();
});
```

I want to test this function in karma. Here's what i thought would work:

```
beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope) {
    rootScope = $rootScope;
}));


it('should reload the window if the url changes', function() {
    spyOn(rootScope, '$on');
    rootScope.$broadcast('$locationChangeSuccess');
    expect(rootScope.$on).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

I've also tried replacing **$broadcast** with **$emit** with the same results, any suggestions on how this should work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot important part of angular - `$digest` cycle
Is it worth remembering for the future if you want to do unit tests, every time you change a model and expect it to trigger something you will need to run `$digest` it's the same when you use `$compile` in unit tests to test directives. Whenever you expect angular to do something automagically you will need to do scope$digest() or rootScope.$digest()

```
beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope) {
    rootScope = $rootScope;
}));


it('should reload the window if the url changes', function() {
    spyOn(rootScope, '$on');
    rootScope.$broadcast('$locationChangeSuccess');
    rootScope.$digest()
    expect(rootScope.$on).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

this will work because the digest cycle will process the broadcast

Comment: this worked perfectly, i'm confused how other questions relating to this have answers that don't include the $digest() but are marked as working. e.g: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32527074/jasmine-test-for-angularjs-locationchangesuccess

Comment: You can catch me on angular IRC channel `maurycyg` if you want to discuss it more ;)